# Search if a registry key exists

Tags: vb.net, .net

Did anybody know any scripts that can search if a specific registry key exists, and if isn't, to create it?

Please write this code in vb.NET ... Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of code using Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey to get you started, from the MSDN documents. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx#Y3876

You should be able to modify this to do a simple loop to search via equals or contains or whatever manner and then to create the key and necessary subkeys.

Comment: It's ok this? Please respond quickly         If Not My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(regKey.ToString, "APP.exe", AppPath) Is Nothing Then    msgbox("exists!")

Comment: It's ok this? Please respond quickly         If Not My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(regKey.ToString, "APP.exe", AppPath) Is Nothing Then    msgbox("exists!")

Comment: where    regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ ... ",true)